# Facebook og:image doesn't load the image

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yoast

When I want to share my blog posts on facebook, the preview image does not load. I debugged the links and it gave the following error.

> Inferred Property
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I am using Yoast SEO plugin and it automatically generates og:image meta before  tag. However, when I viewed the page source, I noticed that Yoast Seo Plugin also created an automatic og:image meta before .

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Yoast Seo Plugin but still the issue did not go away. I installed the Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin on Wordpress and noticed that the Social Media and Share Icons (Ultimate Social Media) plugin was conflicting. I deleted this plugin but still there are 2 of the og:image: url meta (one before  and one before .).

How can I fix this issue?